# Not able to update a progress bar in a separate form using BackgroundWorker c#.net Forms

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.NET. I tried to create a Form with a progess bar from my main UI to show the progress. I used BackgroundWorker to invoke it. I am able to show the progress dialog but not to update the progress bar value. Please find the code below.

**Main UI :**

```
namespace GC
{
    public partial class MainUI : Form
    {
        private ProgressBar oProgressBar;
        public MainUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oProgressBar = new ProgressBar();

            backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);

            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

            oProgressBar.ShowDialog();



        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //some work here

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);


        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            oProgressBar.Close();
        }
        void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            oProgressBar.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        }

    }

}
```

**Progress Bar UI** This form contains a progress bar

```
namespace GC
{
    public partial class ProgressBar : Form
    {
        public ProgressBar()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


      }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Does the bar fill up to 20%?

Comment: may be problem with oProgressBar.ShowDialog(); it halt until u close oProgressBar. but i am not sure.

Comment: You GUI thread is stuck in ShowDialog. GUI will not be updated until you close the dialogue.

Comment: You close the progress bar window a millisecond after you've changed the progress value to 20.  You'll never see it.  ReportProgress() calls must be made *inside* a loop that does work.  If you have no such loop then you can't report progress.  Use the Marquee style instead.

Comment: @musefan  But even up to 20 % fill is not happening :(

Comment: @adrianm That's not true.  `ShowDialog` starts it's own message pump, so even though it's blocking, the UI is still accepting messages and running them.  That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided, there are a couple of things that might be the problem but it depends on what behavior you are experiencing:

**Scenario 1:** Progress bar form closes before seeing any update

The problem is that you are closing the form almost immediately after the progress bar has been updated. This will happen so quick that you will not have time to see the progress bar update.

**Scenario 2:** The Progress bar form remains open, and the bar never updates

This to me would indicate that you have an error in your "Do Work" code that is preventing the `ReportProgress` function from ever being called. To check this I would recommend stepping through the code with the debugger.

---

**What you should do**

Updating the progress bar in a for loop like you have in your example if pointless. You example will cause the progress bar to immediately jump to 20% and stay there. You should be incrementing the progress bar after each "step" in your do work process. Also, it is important that your task actually takes some time to execute (alteast a second) to give it time to display something.

For example, if your task is reading records from a database, then you might for example report progress after each row read. I would also recommend that you wrap it all in a try catch and alert any error (just for know so you can debug your problem)...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Do Stuff: e.g. read from DB
        var tasks = GetTasks();

        int i = 0;
        double percentageIncrease = 100d / tasks.Count();
        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            //do something for this task
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(percentageIncrease * i));
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine for me,

I think your problem is more like:

- The Windows Closed before you see it fill because of:

  oProgressBar.Close();
- As said musefan your bar fill up only to 20%, which is normal because of :

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

If you want to see it totally fill, use a for loop to 100: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)

Comment: But even up to 20 % fill is not happening :(

Comment: Did you try with removing oProgressBar.Close(); ?
Strange because I copied your code and it works fine for me.
maybe I miss something about your backgroundWorker1, where do you declare it? For me it should be a field of your MainUI Form

Answer (score -3):

do you need to invoke the update on the form thread?

```
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    { 
        Invoke(new EventHandler<ProgressChangedEvent>(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged), sender, e);
    }
    else 
        oProgressBar.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, there is no need to invoke when using a background worker in this way

Comment: Really?  Perhaps not in the latest .NET, but in earlier versions, without using Invoke you would get a cross thread exception (i.e. you can only update a control from the thread that created it).

Comment: The "ProgressChanged" event runs on the same thread that started the background worker, which would typically be the main UI thread (and certainly seems to be in this question). So invoking wouldn't be required. Potentially, if you have background workers calling background workers it could get messy... but not sure why you would do that anyway

Comment: Theoretically yes, in the real world, perhaps not.  The InvokeRequired property allows for both cases.